# How can only half a bounty be awarded?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why did I only get 275 rep on an accepted bounty of 500?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43546/why-did-i-only-get-275-rep-on-an-accepted-bounty-of-500)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

I answered [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/) which had an open bounty of 100.

However, I only received 50 rep from it.

<sub>**Edit:** I guess this is by design. Sorry to trouble you all :)</sub>

Comment: Oh, for the love of... read the FAQ!  Previously: [Why did I only get 275 rep on an accepted bounty of 500?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43546/why-did-i-only-get-275-rep-on-an-accepted-bounty-of-500), and explained in [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Hey, so I missed that... no need to downvote!

Comment: maybe if the title didn't include the phrase “ **HORRIBLE GLITCH** ”...

Comment: I love how this question was marked as a duplicate of a question that was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

He didn't select it.

When an answer is auto-accepted, only half the bounty is awarded.

Comment: Oh... *(slaps forehead)*

Comment: @George, my bad. I forgot it did that, too. I should've marked your answer.