# Bounty awarded tooltip doesn't mention the awarder

Tags: support, bounties, tooltips

The second answer in [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l/55247#55247) says "This answer has been awarded bounty worth 100 reputation by ".

This might be because there's another answer that also got awarded a bounty. Or maybe they shared the bounty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question awarded 0 bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82088/question-awarded-0-bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bounty would be from deleted user account "Gnome" according to Gnome's comment.

> Starting a bounty to hopefully bring more attention to this issue. – Gnome Oct 23 '10 at 0:04

Another bounty on another answer is awarded by CaseBash, so they are separate bounties.

Answer (score 2):

Also, when there were [multiple bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5709932/revisions), any missing deleted/merged user might make this look like another user granted the full amount:

[image]

...which before merging [showed as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131521/bounty-of-2600-did-the-bounty-rules-change):

[image]

Comment: I wanted to report small issue - when same user grant more than one bounty on same answer his name would appear twice which does not sound right. Forgot about that until seeing this, think it deserve its own report?