# Bounty of 2600? Did the bounty rules change?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Something seems wrong with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250823/620338). Have the bounty rules changed? Seems that the same bounty was awarded several times to the same user.

[image]

Comment: 7 times, actually. `2050` rep in 6 bounties from the user [abcdefghi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/726802/abcdefghi), `50` rep from somebody else. Must be a **really** good answer.

Comment: Though it may be some strange sock puppety way to give rep?

Comment: @Michael, the dupe might explain how 2,600 is possible, but I somehow feel that [one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/726802/abcdefghi) is transferring rep to another. Not sure if that's a problem, but it somehow smells.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, @Arjan, and I'd take back my close vote if I could.

Comment: And talking [to one another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296873/phone-number-textbox-issue/10296921#comment13250716_10296921), but that does not prove it's not the same person of course...

Comment: It's likely the same person. [abcdefghi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/726802/abcdefghi?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1) account who was previously relatively active abruptly became inactive around the moment [Guest](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1339428/guest?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1) account was registered (17 April). The writing style is also extremely similar.

Comment: Bah, too bad the bounties were refunded... it should have been confiscated and some suspensions to be handed out.

Comment: The rules haven't changed, and as others have pointed out, this type of thing looks awfully fishy. But it's probably something you should flag for moderator attention. They have the tools to investigate stuff like this, and will take action if it's warranted.

Comment: Also, it appears that this has been taken care of already. The two accounts have been merged, and the user has been suspended.

Comment: @The This has apparently been a bug. So would you recommend to _not_ report bugs here but only flag it?

Comment: What gave you the impression that this was a bug?

Comment: @The It's a matter of definition. If the system allows somehow to add and award 7 bounties within a few days from the same person on the same question. I understand your point of view that it may not be a bug, however I think the discussion here helped to solve _it_.

Comment: @The My first impression yesterday when I encountered this issue was that the system accidently awarded the bounty multiple times to the user. That's why I thought it was a bug.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The tooltip (hover over the +2600) shows the answer got 7 (!) bounties rewarded to it.

[image]

Since most of this came from one user, with a dubious user name (abcdefghi - really?) and accounts for pretty much all of the rep of the account that answered it, there certainly is something fishy going on.

Comment: *there certainly is something fishy going on*. One user transferring his rep to another, maybe?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - Yes, certainly looks like it.

Comment: Now that Robert removed the active bounty, and the user and its puppet were merged and suspended, the tooltip [is no longer correct](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZS1.png)... (And OnResolve [is unrelated to the abusing user](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5709932/revisions).)

Comment: (But I *think* I've seen an earlier bug report for that...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835899/mailto-using-browser-options-in-new-window-ie-8/9878776#9878776 I was in the running for this one when on the last day he awarded the bounty to his other account (at that time, both were named 'Pankaj Garj' or something). Those two accounts were merged, but I didn't know he was still going at it